# Relação entre Python Arrays

Tags: python-2.7, array-associativo

sou iniciante em Python e estou com muita dificuldade em fazer o seguinte:

Possuo 1 vetor com os seguintes valores:

- posição = [34.53, 32.64, 44.20, 43.41]

Estes valores são dados pela distância Euclidiana das seguintes coordenadas:

- coordenadas = [29, 83, 61, 70, 29, 83, 50, 58, 29, 83, 64, 56, 29, 83, 71, 72]

A cada 4 índices do vetor coordenadas, corresponde a 1 índice do vetor posição.

- Por exemplo: O valor [34.53] do vetor posição, corresponde aos valores [29, 83, 61, 70] do vetor coordenadas.

==================

O que eu desejo fazer é o seguinte:

Quando um valor do meu **vetor posição** for maior que 40.00, devo modificar as coordenadas correspondentes no **vetor coordenadas** por outros valores definidos de forma aleatória.

Por exemplo:

- Possuo os seguintes vetores:

posição = [40.51, 30.52, 30.31]

coordenadas = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]

- Localizei um valor maior que 40.00 no vetor posição.

posição = [**40.51**, 30.52, 30.31]

- Que correspondem a esses 4 índices do vetor coordenadas.

coordenadas = [**10, 20, 30, 40**, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]

- Devo substituir os valores do vetor coordenadas, por esses:

coordenadas = [**200, 130, 67, 31**, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]

=================

Desculpem-me caso ainda não esteja muito claro, tentei ser o mais didático possível.

Peço que me ajudem, realmente não sei como posso resolver isso. Me parece simples, mas ainda sou iniciante.

Fico muito agradecido aos que se dispuserem em me ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para conseguir isso pode percorrer o primeiro array através da posição e testar se o valor é acima de `40` com um `if`. Caso seja acede ao segundo array multiplicando a posição por 4 e acedendo 4 elementos de cada vez. Para cada um dos elementos acedidos gera um novo utilizando o `randrange` do python:

```
import random

posicao = [40.51, 30.52, 30.31]
coordenadas = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]

for indice in range(0, len(posicao)):
    if posicao[indice]>40: #se maior que 40
         for indice2 in range(indice*4, indice*4+4): #aceder aos correspondentes        
            coordenadas[indice2] = random.randrange(0,200) #gerar os aleatorios entre 0 e 200


print(coordenadas)
```

[Exemplo a funcionar no Ideone para testar](http://ideone.com/w11ZiJ)

Comment: Isac, estou realmente agradecido pela sua ajuda.

Muito Obrigado por disponibilizar um pouco do seu tempo para me ajudar.

muito, muito obrigado!

Comment: @Danilo Sem problema, resto de bom desenvolvimento.